# Why does Codeigniter 2 routing work but not on Codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I am developing a project on codeigniter 3, but I have a routing problem.

```
$route['forgot-password'] = "Auth/forgot_password";
```

when I request the url it shows an error, the error is given below

```
http://localhost/myproject/forgot-password/404
```

It works fine on Codeigniter 2 but not working on Codeigniter 3.

Thanks in advance

Comment: plz share the error you are getting

Comment: http://localhost/myproject/index.php/forgot-password/404

Comment: it shows 404 in the url that is the problem, it always redirect me on 404

Comment: are you also putting  extra parameter after forgot-password like http://localhost/myproject/forgot-password//{parameter}

Comment: you can change routes name like **$route['forgot-password'] = "auth/forgot_password";** and  check controller name first character as Capital for ex : **class Auth extends MY_Controller**

Comment: On codeigniter 3 did you follow this set up for controller file names and classes http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world

Comment: You also must set your base url in CI3 as well.

Comment: i already did @NikunjRathod

Comment: i already did @wolfgang1983

Comment: Try change on routes.php `$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;`
to `$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE;`

Comment: Try this `$route['forgot-password/(:any)'] = "auth/forgot_password/$1";` and here are some more htaccess https://github.com/wolfgang1983/htaccess_for_codeigniter and http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = TRUE; is not working @wolfgang1983

Comment: Have you tried `$route['forgot-password/(:any)'] = "auth/forgot_password/$1";` http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: after using $route['forgot-password/(:any)'] = "auth/forgot_password/$1" I have got my view but it shows 404 in the url http://localhost/codeigniter_migrate_2_3/forgot-password/404

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120083/discussion-between-wolfgang1983-and-snehasish-sarker).

Answer (score 0):

in codeigniter 3

```
$route['forgot-password'] = "Auth/forgot_password";
```

change to

```
$route['forgot-password/(:any)'] = "Auth/forgot_password/$1";
```

or just number

```
$route['forgot-password/(:num)'] = "Auth/forgot_password/$1";
```

create file .htaccess in root proje
and append code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: after using $route['forgot-password/(:any)'] = "auth/forgot_password/$1" I have got my view but it shows 404 in the url localhost/codeigniter_migrate_2_3/forgot-password/404